# Como organizar questões para exibir na tela

Tags: java, html, css, jsf, primefaces

boa noite. 
Tenho um atributo do tipo String que recebe uma pergunta vinda diretamente de um textArea. O meu problema é que não consigo deixar as questões na hora de exibir igual como cadastro elas.

Ex:

**Cadastro uma questão assim:**

```
Questão? 
A)
B)
C)
D)
```

Recupero as questões e jogo em uma List, uma `List<Questoes> questoes` e na hora de exibir a questão em um dataTable elas são exibidas assim:

```
Questão?  A) B) C) D)
```

ou seja, tudo na mesma linha. Alguém pode me ajudar? Segue os códigos relacionados.

```
@Column(name = "PERGUNTA")
private String pergunta;
```

XHTML:

```
<p:outputLabel value="Descricao do Item:" for="descItem"
                    style="font-weight:bold" />
                <p:inputTextarea id="descItem" required="true"
                    requiredMessage="Por favor, elabore a pergunta."
                    value="#{cadastroQuestaoBean.questao.pergunta}" cols="120" rows="2"
                    autoResize="true" label="descItem" />
```

DataTable aonde são exibidas as perguntas:

```
<p:dataTable id="exibePerguntas" var="questao" paginator="true"
                rowsPerPageTemplate="3,5,10,12" paginatorPosition="bottom"
                value="#{gerarSimuladoBean.questoes}">
                <p:column headerText="Perguntas">
                    <br></br>
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{questao.pergunta}" />
                </p:column>
     </p:dataTable />
```

Answer (score 0):

Primeiramente: Tá faltando um `</p:column>` aí, pra fechar seu tag `<p:column>`

Tenta colocar assim:

```
<p:column headerText="Perguntas">
    <h:outputText value="#{questao.pergunta}"/>
</p:column>
```

Comment: Não foi brother.